# How to evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^1 e^{ax^2+bx+c\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration

Can anyone show if the following integral can be evaluated in closed form? 
\begin{equation}
\int_{-1}^1 e^{ax^2+bx+c\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
\end{equation}
The variable $x$ can be replaced by $\cos{\theta}$, with corresponding change of the interval of integration.

Comment: are you looking to show that it CAN be integrated? or to find a closed form for the integral. because the former probably easier in this case.

Comment: Closed form seems unlikely..

Comment: Do you think that a closed form could exist for the antiderivative ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici not at all, the combination of the $ a x^2+c \sqrt{1-x^2}$ seems not very promising

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I don't know if it exists. I have modified the question to reflect that.

Comment: @tired. I bet that *not very promising* is an understatement ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici True :) But it may be possible to make some nice asymptotics in some of the parameters....

Comment: @tired. I agree, for sure. Taylor expansion will work.

Comment: @tired, the OP didn't mention asymptotics at all, so the tag isn't relevant.  I'm rolling back the edit.

Comment: @AntonioVargas but it is the best what u can do with this integral. Maybe he should give us a hint if he is interested or not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can't be a closed form for that integral. If there was a closed form, $I(a,b,c)$, then set $b=c=0$ and $a=-1$ to get a closed form for $\int_{-1}^{1} e^{-x^2}dx$, which has been shown to not exist.

Comment: Brillant, a well deserved  (+1)!